# Text Only Detail View From RSS Parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm new with the objective-c programming, but so far i manage to do a custom splitview which parse an rss link of news list in tableview on the rootview. When the link selected it will open the url in detailed view.The problem is i can only show the full html in uiwebview. What i want is that the detail view to display only text and the image (just like the BBC-News app), I tried the stringWithContentsOfURL and stripped the html tag, but it display the whole string from head to footer. I just wanted the body content. Is there anyway i can achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the XMLParser then you should apply didStartElement method use this method and make a check for what ever part you want with simple syntax

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"body"])
```

use this type of if/else check to refine what ever that you want and save in an array according to your data Class then when you retrive data at the time of detail view use this array and tie with particular data whatever you want to show in your details view.

Like:-

```
label.text = array.title;
```

Hope this will help you...